# Reuse controller / model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to reuse my code so I'm not repeating me self. 
I have made PostController and Post model. Now I want to create admin view page where I can CRUD my posts. Problem is here how to reuse Postcontroller to my admin view ?

to mentioned I'm new to Laravel

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('posts.post', compact('posts'));
    } ...


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;

class AdminController extends PostsController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('admin.index', compact('posts'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use single PostController for frontend and admin then you have to check currently logged in guard is **admin** or **user** to render view :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

  class PostsController extends Controller
  {

     public function index()
     {
        $posts = Post::all();
        @if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
           return view('admin.index', compact('posts'));
        @elseif(Auth::guard('user')->check())
           return view('posts.post', compact('posts'));
        @endif
     } 
 }
```